# How do I get my USB HD to be detected after SW update?

Tags: usb, update-manager, usb-drive

This is Ubuntu 21.04 on a System76 Ratel Pro.
Today, I took a software update that involved kernel modules (and required adm password). When I tried to restart as instructed, the restart hung until I unplugged my USB backup drive, at which point the system came up immediately. Now when I plug the drive into (any) USB socket, it is not detected (does not show up on the desktop nor in /media/david). When I type lsusb I get the same 6 lines whether or not the drive is plugged in. Is my drive no longer supported after the update?

Comment: Very odd. What kind of drive is this? Do you know the brand and model?

Comment: Hi. Please connect the drive and bring up disks to see if the drive has the parittions and is working. One guess (assuming is external ntfs formated) is that was not closed properly and need to be checked.

Comment: It does not show up in disks. I believe it was ext4 but it could be ext2. Definitely one of those.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't responded to matigo. It is iomega MDHD250-U,

Comment: Okay, more details. uname -r now shows 5.11.0-7620-generic. By looking in /lib/modules, it may be that before this latest update, I would have been at 5.11.0-7614-generic. Is there a way to revert?

Comment: I managed to get it to boot to the previous kernel but it is still not detecting the drive.